# Can someone explain why we take Second Countability and Hausdorffness conditions in Manifold definition?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The definition of Differential Manifold or Smooth Manifold include $\text{Second countability}$ and $\text{Hausdorffness condition}$.

My question is why we include Second countability and Hausdorffness in the defintition of Differentiable manifold?

I got something from a online article that **Second countability** is used to exclude **large space** .

But I could not mean it.

Can someone explain why we take Second Countability and Hausdorffness condition ?

Comment: @user549397, it is extra property that the manifold is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is second countable and housdorff. But why we are taking the second count ability and Housdorffness condition separately?

Comment: Not sure about what you say @user549387. I mean the line with two origins is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ but it isn't Hausdorff. [Here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/the-line-with-two-origins/) I attach you a link.

Comment: @Dog_69 Yep, you are right! Another helpful post I found: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/709777/549397

Comment: See: Why is important for a manifold to have countable basis? 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2131530/549397

Comment: @user549397 Really interesting :)

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472998/why-do-we-need-hausdorff-ness-in-definition-of-topological-manifold